# C++: Is the ignored return value destruction behavior well-defined

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

**Question:** Is an ignored return value destructed immediately or at the moment going out of scope.?

The code below returns for my compiler

Output:

> Who makes it, has no need of it.
>
> Who buys it, has no use for it.
>
> Who uses it can neither see nor feel it.
>
> What is it?

Therefore the ignored value is destructed immediatly. But is this compiler specific or standard-behavior?

```
struct foo
{
   ~foo()
   {
      std::cout << "Who makes it, has no need of it. \n"
                << "Who buys it, has no use for it. \n";
   }
}

foo createFoo()
{
   return foo();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     createFoo();
     std::cout << "Who uses it can neither see nor feel it.\n"
               << "What is it?"; 
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The returned temporary is destroyed immediately after the full expression completes *except* if its lifetime is extended by being bound to an rvalue or const lvalue reference.

Comment: ... or to an rvalue reference.

Comment: maybe an example would be helpful

Comment: Just remove the word "const".  Also, the verb is *destroyed*.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Unfortunately if I remove the word `const` then it sounds like you can bind a return by-value to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: @MarkB: I disagree that it makes any claim about the particularities of the reference binding rules.  For example, you don't feel compelled to explain polymorphism and binding to a base-typed reference here, do you?

Answer (score 5):

In the standard 5.11 has

> In some contexts, an expression only appears for its side effects. Such an expression is called a discarded-value
>   expression. The expression is evaluated and its value is discarded.

So when the expression ends the value is then discarded and if it is a class type then the destructor is called.

Comment: In addition to this, 12.8.32 points out that  the compiler MAY omit copying of the return value, as it did here.  A different compiler may print the first half of the riddle twice because it would destroy one copy as it left `createFoo`'s scope and once on the line in `main` calling `createFoo`, as Nathan's answer points out.

Answer (score 4):

[§12.2 /3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)

> **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step
>   in evaluating the full-expression** (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects of destroying
>   a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

Exceptions are for constructor arguments, and for binding references to a temporary. (§12.3/4f.)

Comment: Particularly, only temporaries created by constructor default arguments.

Comment: There's an additional exception that occurs when initializing arrays.